# require is not defined error in backend node js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

My nodejs js file throws error "ReferenceError: require is not defined" when executed under CLI nodejs context. However, executing "console.log(require)" in nodejs REPL interactive shell returns a valid function definition.

```
$ cat r.js
console.log(require);

$ node
Welcome to Node.js v12.17.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> console.log(require);
[Function: require] {
  resolve: [Function: resolve] { paths: [Function: paths] },
  main: undefined,
  extensions: [Object: null prototype] {
    '.js': [Function],
    '.json': [Function],
    '.node': [Function]
  },
  cache: [Object: null prototype] {}
}
undefined

$ node r.js
(node:8341) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///work/testnodejs/r.js:1
console.log(require);
        ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///work/testnodejs/r.js:1:13
```

Comment: You can't use `require` along with ES6 imports.

Comment: I am not using ES6 imports in r.js. It is a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing console.log(require) under node's REPL.

```
> console.log(require);
[Function: require] {
  resolve: [Function: resolve] { paths: [Function: paths] },
  main: undefined,
  extensions: [Object: null prototype] {
    '.js': [Function],
    '.json': [Function],
    '.node': [Function]
  },
  cache: [Object: null prototype] {}
}
undefined
```

Executing under CLI nodejs context (just with one statement console.log(require);)

```
node helloWorld.js
Function: require] {
  resolve: [Function: resolve] { paths: [Function: paths] },
  main: Module {
    id: '.',
    path: '/Applications/node-course',
    exports: {},
    parent: null,
    filename: '/Applications/node-course/helloWorld.js',
    loaded: false,
    children: [],
    paths: [
      '/Applications/node-course/node_modules',
      '/Applications/node_modules',
      '/node_modules'
    ]
  },
  extensions: [Object: null prototype] {
    '.js': [Function],
    '.json': [Function],
    '.node': [Function]
  },
  cache: [Object: null prototype] {
    '/Applications/node-course/helloWorld.js': Module {
      id: '.',
      path: '/Applications/node-course',
      exports: {},
      parent: null,
      filename: '/Applications/node-course/helloWorld.js',
      loaded: false,
      children: [],
      paths: [Array]
    }
  }
}
```

require is a builtin function within Node.js, providing easiest way to include modules that exist in separate files.
Reference [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/)

As long as you have installed node globally in your machine and executing console.log(require) in node's context, will print the function definition as above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Yes, I am aware how require work. The problem is require function is not defined in the global scope when I run nodejs in CLI mode. This is problematic because I can't use mocha to run my tests.

Is it possible that my global node installation is corrupted?

Comment: Just a clarification. Does your package.json has "type": "module" defined. If So ,then please remove it or change it to "type": "commonjs" to use require.  Reference related to similar issue - https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2436